# How to create a popUp in unity3d?

Tags: unity-game-engine, popup

I want to create a **PopUp** for my game, my requirement is to open a popUp when user click a button.
And popUp contains a image for its background, a close button on upper-right corner and two buttons on the popUp (lets say YES & NO).
I make R&D but nothing found relevant.
Any help would be appriciated.

P.S. I don't want to use any third party plugIn Like NGUI, 2D ToolKit etc.

Comment: Which version of Unity3D are you using? (If it's the 4.6, you have a pretty good enhanced GUI toolset)

Comment: @Gounemond: I am using Unity 4.5.2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Unity till 4.5**

You can build most components with `GUITexture` wiht the legacy UI system.

http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-GuiTexture.html

Build your background and buttons from textures of the scheme below. For the buttons you also use `GUIText` and make the clickable/touchable.

[image]

For more info see the scripting guide.

http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/GUIScriptingGuide.html

**Unity 4.6 or newer**

The GUI system of Unity easily allows you to do that. You will need a `Canvas` and a `Sprite` for the background. And two buttons as children for YES and NO.

[image]

See the introduction first
http://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/live-training-archive/the-new-ui

The manual shows all components
http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UISystem.html

GUI Reference
http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GUI.html

Comment: thanks for your support, but in my unity editor (version 4.5.2), i am not able to find Menu->GameObject->UI, Ui is not available in editor. Wat i have to do..

Comment: @Akshay Ah, I am sorry. The features mentioned are available from version 4.6 on.

Comment: thanx for the quick response, any workaround to achive my requirement in same version, or if i build the popup using unity 4.6, then it will not work on lower versions of unity editor..

Comment: @Akshay The you have the to use the legacy GUI system with `GUITexture` and `GUIText`. See my answer for details.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating something like this for the pop-up button(JavaScript):

```
var popupactive : boolean = false;
var (Name of the GUI window) : GUITexture;
var (Picture1) : GUITexture;
var (Picture2) : GUITexture;
var (Picture3) : GUITexture;
(Name off the GUI window).enabled = false;
(Picture1).enabled = false;
(Picture2).enabled = false;
(Picture3).enabled = false;   

function OnMouseUp(){
   if(popupactive==false){
       popupactive = true;
       }
       else{
       popupactive = false;
       (Name of the GUI window).enabled = false;
       }
}
```

Then try adding a function that closes the GUI for the exit button and "no" button to close the opened GUIs, Also remember to import the separate scripts assigned to the separate buttons inside the code! Remember also to assign them in the Unity editor. Hope it helps!